# Auth0 Authentication and Google Calendar Request Flow

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-calendar-api, auth0

I'm building a web app where I show a user's google calendar event's augmented with some other information.

My plan is to authenticate the user with the correct scopes using auth0. I have done this.

I get back a response that looks something like this

```
access_token: "ACCESS TOKEN BLAH BLAH"
expires_in: 86400
id_token: "JWT TOKEK BLAH"
scope: "openid profile email calendar"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

Is it the access token that I'm given here that I send to the google calendar api? I decoded the jwt token in id token and there doesn't seem to be any tokens in there just user info.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/calling-an-external-idp-api

Comment: Hi ! If what you are trying is to retrieve information from the user's calendar then you should be looking at [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar) which uses Google Authorization [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth). Could you also please share a sample code where you are implementing this integration with Google Calendar API (with no sensitive data) ? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf. I figured out what I need to do :) When using auth0 to authenticate with google they don't give you the IDP token by default. I need to request it using the auth0 management api which I can then send to google. So the flow would be take jwt token given to me by auth0 in my frontend. Send that to backend. Decode it. Then ask auth0 for the idptoken for google for that user. Then send that to google when requesting the calendar.

Comment: Hi ! I'm glad you managed to solve your problem. Could you please post an answer with the contents of the comment explaining how you solved your question so that other users with similar questions can easily find the solution to their problems? Thanks ! :D

Answer (score -1):

The answer can be found here - https://auth0.com/docs/connections/calling-an-external-idp-api

You need to use the auth0 management API get a user's IDP token. This is the token you send to google's APIs